# laravel 5.2 nested Where clause

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5, where-clause

How to perform a where clause using laravel eloquent with the following query:

```
select * from stats where payed = 1 AND WHERE (user_id = 1 OR owner_id = 1)
```

I don't know how to modify this code for this:

```
    $payouts = Stat::where('payed', '1')
            ->???(function ($query) {
                $query->where('owner_id', Auth::user()->id)
                      ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
            })->get();
```

Comment: This is very clearly doumented in the [laravel fluent docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#advanced-where-clauses)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change like this

```
$payouts = Stat::where('payed', '1');
        $payouts->where(function ($payouts) {
            $payouts->where('owner_id', Auth::user()->id)
                  ->orWhere('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
        })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $payouts = Stat::where('payed', '1')
            ->where(function ($query) {
              $query->where('owner_id', Auth::user()->id)
                        ->orwhere('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
             })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close, this should do the trick:

```
$payouts = Stat::where('payed', '1')
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('owner_id', Auth::user()->id)
                      ->orWhere('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
            })->get();
```

This is looking for `where payed = 1 AND (owner_id is the current user ID OR the user_id is the current user ID)`